# Firebug breakpoint prevents jquery execution

Tags: firebug, breakpoints

Example jquery:

```
request.done(function(response) { 
    alert('Done');
});
```

If a breakpoint is placed next to the 'alert' statement, then the alert is still executed.

But if the breakpoint is placed next to 'request.done', then the alert (and all other statements in the function) is not executed - or appears not to be executed. Maybe it is executed on the console, but the view is not updated.

Ps. This resulted in quite strong language being used, after I spent many hours changing all my code to try and locate my "non-existing" error :)

Any other hidden secrets I should know about Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is good. What you have to do is, you just reset firebug setting.It will work fine.No problem   :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. What firebug setting are you referring to? Or how do you reset firebug?